# Practical uses of TypedReference

Tags: c#, .net, typedreference

Are there any practical uses of the [`TypedReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typedreference.aspx) struct that you would actually use in real code?

**EDIT**: The .Net framework uses them in overloads of `Console.WriteLine` and `String.Concat` which build an array from an `__arglist` parameter and pass it to the normal `params` overload.  Why do these overloads exist?

Comment: Why is this not constructive? :o

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764573/why-is-typedreference-behind-the-scenes-its-so-fast-and-safe-almost-magical

Comment: You can also use it to pass stack location / variable reference "around" (e.g. to other thread or return it from method). It requires unsafe code and "copying" TypedReference as two IntPtr.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Are there any practical uses of the TypedReference struct that you would actually use in real code?

Yes. I'd use them if I needed interoperability with C-style variadic methods.

> Why do these overloads exist?

They exist for interoperability with callers who like to use C-style variadic methods.

Comment: +1 for not slamming the C-style varidiac bits :) And here's to hope you'll have variadic templates (not generics) by 5.0.

Answer (score 17):

This appears to be a very old question, but I'd like to add one more use-case: when you have a struct and want to set its variable through reflection, you would always operate on the boxed value and never change the original. This is useless:

```
TestFields fields = new TestFields { MaxValue = 1234 };
FieldInfo info = typeof(TestFields).GetField("MaxValue");
info.SetValue(fields, 4096);

// result: fields.MaxValue is still 1234!!
```

This can be remedied with implied boxing, but then you loose type safety. Instead, you can fix this with a `TypedParameter`:

```
TestFields fields = new TestFields { MaxValue = 1234 };
FieldInfo info = fields.GetType().GetField("MaxValue");

TypedReference reference = __makeref(fields);
info.SetValueDirect(reference, 4096);

// result: fields.MaxValue is now indeed 4096!!
```

Comment: I don't know if I would call this a Reflection specific issue. `SetValue` takes an object as input, so any value type will be boxed to match the signature of the method.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: afaik, this reflection-specific behavior stems from Reflection predating generics, otherwise boxing would not be needed. On (pre-)boxed value types and references this problem does not arise.

Comment: My point was just that any method that takes `object` as input (which the first overload of `SetValue` in your example does) will force values to be boxed. That's how the unified type system handles values. That is not specific to Reflection.

Comment: Yes, and then the system introduced `ref` to work with value references, but SetXXX do not have ref-overloads. Indeed, the system is designed this way, isn't that the sole reason they added `SetValueDirect` and hence had to introduce an object that is both a reference to a value and an object?