# Why is TypedReference behind the scenes? It's so fast and safe... almost magical!

Tags: c#, typedreference

Warning: This question is a bit heretical... religious programmers always abiding by good practices, please don't read it. :)

Does anyone know why the use of [TypedReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typedreference%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is so discouraged (implicitly, by lack of documentation)?

I've found great uses for it, such as when passing generic parameters through functions that shouldn't be generic (when using an `object` might be overkill or slow, if you need a value type), for when you need an opaque pointer, or for when you need to access an element of an array quickly, whose specs you find at runtime (using `Array.InternalGetReference`). Since the CLR doesn't even allow incorrect usage of this type, why is it discouraged? It doesn't seem to be unsafe or anything...

---

Other uses I've found for `TypedReference`:

"Specializing" generics in C# (this is type-safe):

```
static void foo<T>(ref T value)
{
    //This is the ONLY way to treat value as int, without boxing/unboxing objects
    if (value is int)
    { __refvalue(__makeref(value), int) = 1; }
    else { value = default(T); }
}
```

Writing code that works with generic pointers (this is *very* unsafe if misused, but fast and safe if used correctly):

```
//This bypasses the restriction that you can't have a pointer to T,
//letting you write very high-performance generic code.
//It's dangerous if you don't know what you're doing, but very worth if you do.
static T Read<T>(IntPtr address)
{
    var obj = default(T);
    var tr = __makeref(obj);

    //This is equivalent to shooting yourself in the foot
    //but it's the only high-perf solution in some cases
    //it sets the first field of the TypedReference (which is a pointer)
    //to the address you give it, then it dereferences the value.
    //Better be 10000% sure that your type T is unmanaged/blittable...
    unsafe { *(IntPtr*)(&tr) = address; }

    return __refvalue(tr, T);
}
```

Writing a *method* version of the `sizeof` instruction, which can be occasionally useful:

```
static class ArrayOfTwoElements<T> { static readonly Value = new T[2]; }

static uint SizeOf<T>()
{
    unsafe 
    {
        TypedReference
            elem1 = __makeref(ArrayOfTwoElements<T>.Value[0] ),
            elem2 = __makeref(ArrayOfTwoElements<T>.Value[1] );
        unsafe
        { return (uint)((byte*)*(IntPtr*)(&elem2) - (byte*)*(IntPtr*)(&elem1)); }
    }
}
```

Writing a method that passes a "state" parameter that wants to avoid boxing:

```
static void call(Action<int, TypedReference> action, TypedReference state)
{
    //Note: I could've said "object" instead of "TypedReference",
    //but if I had, then the user would've had to box any value types
    try
    {
        action(0, state);
    }
    finally { /*Do any cleanup needed*/ }
}
```

So why are uses like this "discouraged" (by lack of documentation)? Any particular safety reasons? It seems perfectly safe and verifiable if it's not mixed with pointers (which aren't safe or verifiable anyway)...

---

Update:

Sample code to show that, indeed, `TypedReference` can be twice as fast (or more):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
static class Program
{
    static void Set1<T>(T[] a, int i, int v)
    { __refvalue(__makeref(a[i]), int) = v; }

    static void Set2<T>(T[] a, int i, int v)
    { a[i] = (T)(object)v; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = new List<object>();
        var rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        { root.Add(new byte[rand.Next(1024 * 64)]); }
        //The above code is to put just a bit of pressure on the GC

        var arr = new int[5];
        int start;
        const int COUNT = 40000000;

        start = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        { Set1(arr, 0, i); }
        Console.WriteLine("Using TypedReference:  {0} ticks",
                          Environment.TickCount - start);
        start = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        { Set2(arr, 0, i); }
        Console.WriteLine("Using boxing/unboxing: {0} ticks",
                          Environment.TickCount - start);

        //Output Using TypedReference:  156 ticks
        //Output Using boxing/unboxing: 484 ticks
    }
}
```

(Edit: I edited the benchmark above, since the last version of the post used a debug version of the code [I forgot to change it to release], and put no pressure on the GC. This version is a bit more realistic, and on my system, it's more than three times faster with `TypedReference` on average.)

Comment: When I run your example I get completely different results. `TypedReference: 203 ticks`, `boxing/unboxing: 31 ticks`. No matter what I try (including different ways to do the timing) the boxing/unboxing is still faster on my system.

Comment: @Seph: I just saw your comment. That's *very* interesting -- it seems to be faster on x64, but slower on x86. Weird...

Comment: There is a marked difference between x64, x86, and Any CPU build configurations. 
x86: boxing/unboxing is slightly faster.
x64: TypedReference is ~30% faster.
Any CPU: Typed Reference ~10% faster.


Any CPU is also the slowest of the above overall, and x86 is the fastest by 3x.

Comment: I just tested that benchmark code on my x64 machine under .NET 4.5. I replaced Environment.TickCount with Diagnostics.Stopwatch and went with ms instead of ticks. I ran each build (x86, 64, Any) three times. The best out of three results were as follws:

x86: 205/27ms (same result for 2/3 runs on this build)
x64: 218/109ms
Any: 205/27ms (same result for 2/3 runs on this build)

In -all- cases box/unboxing was faster.

Comment: You can't have `Action<int, TypedReference>`. It is such a special type it cannot be used as a type argument (imagine how many troubles it could cause). Of course, you can make a normal delegate type that uses it.

Comment: The strange speed measurements might be attributed to these two facts:
* (T)(object)v does NOT actually make a heap allocation. In .NET 4+ it's optimized away. There are no allocations on this path, and it's damn fast.
* Using makeref requires the variable to be actually allocated on the stack (while the kinda-box method might optimize it into registers). Also, by looking at the timings, I assume that it impairs inlining even with the force-inline flag. So kinda-box is inlined and enregistered, while makeref makes a function call and operates the stack

Comment: To see the profits of typeref casting, make it less trivial. E.g. casting an underlying type to the enum type (`int`->`DockStyle`). This boxes for real, and is nearly ten times slower.

Comment: Your `foo` method actually **does** box by using the `is` keyword. It compiles as `IL_0002: box !!T` `IL_0007: isinst [mscorlib]System.Int32`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Ok, thanks for clarifying the cultural point. Downvote retracted.

Comment: This `SizeOf` actually wouldn't work because the GC can move objects. That can change the pointer values.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Short answer: **portability**.

While `__arglist`, `__makeref`, and `__refvalue` are *language extensions* and are undocumented in the C# Language Specification, the constructs used to implement them under the hood (`vararg` calling convention, `TypedReference` type, `arglist`, `refanytype`, `mkanyref`, and `refanyval` instructions) are perfectly documented in the [CLI Specification (ECMA-335)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) in the **Vararg library**.

Being defined in the Vararg Library makes it quite clear that they are primarily meant to support variable-length argument lists and not much else.  Variable-argument lists have little use in platforms that don't need to interface with external C code that uses varargs.  For this reason, the Varargs library is not part of any CLI profile. Legitimate CLI implementations may choose not to support Varargs library as it's not included in the CLI Kernel profile:

> ### 4.1.6 Vararg
>
> The **vararg feature set** supports variable-length argument lists and runtime-typed pointers.
>
> **If omitted:** Any attempt to reference a method with the `vararg` calling convention or the signature encodings associated with vararg methods (see Partition II) shall throw the `System.NotImplementedException` exception. Methods using the CIL instructions `arglist`, `refanytype`, `mkrefany`, and `refanyval` shall throw the `System.NotImplementedException` exception. The precise timing of the exception is not specified. The type `System.TypedReference` need not be defined.

#### Update (reply to `GetValueDirect` comment):

`FieldInfo.GetValueDirect` are `FieldInfo.SetValueDirect` are **not** part of Base Class Library. Note that there's a difference between .NET Framework Class Library and Base Class Library. BCL is the only thing required for a conforming implementation of the CLI/C# and is documented in [ECMA TR/84](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/techreports/E-TR-084.htm). (In fact, `FieldInfo` itself is part of the Reflection library and that's not included in CLI Kernel profile either).

As soon as you use a method outside BCL, you are giving up a bit of portability (and this is becoming increasingly important with the advent of non-.NET CLI implementations like Silverlight and MonoTouch).  Even if an implementation wanted to increase compatiblility with the Microsoft .NET Framework Class Library, it could simply provide `GetValueDirect` and `SetValueDirect` taking a `TypedReference` without making the `TypedReference` specially handled by the runtime (basically, making them equivalent to their `object` counterparts without the performance benefit).

Had they documented it in C#, it would have had at least a couple implications:

1. Like any feature, it *may* become a roadblock to new features, especially since this one doesn't really fit in the design of C# and requires weird syntax extensions and special handing of a type by the runtime.
2. All implementations of C# have to somehow implement this feature and it's not necessarily trivial/possible for C# implementations that don't run on top of a CLI at all or run on top of a CLI without Varargs.

Comment: Good arguments for portability, +1. But what about `FieldInfo.GetValueDirect` and `FieldInfo.SetValueDirect`? They're part of the BCL, and to use them you *need* `TypedReference`, so doesn't that basically force `TypedReference` to always be defined, regardless of the language spec? (Also, another note: Even if the keywords didn't exist, as long as the instructions existed, you could still access them by dynamically emitting methods... so as long as your platform interops with C libraries, you can use these, whether or not C# has the keywords.)

Comment: Oh, and another issue: Even if it's not portable, why did they not document the keywords? At the very least, it's necessary when interoping with C varargs, so at least they could've mentioned it?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Huh, that's interesting. I guess I always assumed that files in the *BCL* folder of the .NET source are part of the BCL, never really paying attention to the ECMA standardization part. This is pretty convincing... except one little thing: isn't it a bit pointless to even include the (optional) feature in the CLI spec, if there's no documentation on how to use it anywhere? (It would make sense if `TypedReference` was documented just for one language -- say, managed C++ -- but if *no* language documents it and so if no one can really use it, then why even bother defining the feature?)

Comment: @Mehrdad I *suspect* the primary motivation was the need for this feature internally for interop (*e.g.* `[DllImport("...")] void Foo(__arglist);`) and they implemented it in C# for their own use. Design of the CLI is influenced by a lot of languages (annotations "The Common Language Infrastructure Annotated Standard" demonstrate this fact.) Being a suitable runtime for as many languages as possible, including unforeseen ones, has definitely been a design goal (hence the name) and this is a feature that, for instance, a hypothetical managed C implementation could probably benefit from.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Ah... yeah, that's a pretty convincing reason. Thanks!

Comment: @Mehrdad its not actually much different than ref variables and ByReference<T> (which also can only live on stack) hidden in new Span<T> class which impementation provided by CLR as intrinsics. and im 100% sure it will continue to be supported forever not only for this similarities but lots of consumer code depends on it..

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest your comment was 8 years apart from the answer. World changes  :)

Answer (score 15):

Well, I'm no Eric Lippert, so I can't speak directly of Microsoft's motivations, but if I were to venture a guess, I'd say that `TypedReference` et al. aren't well documented because, frankly, you don't need them.

Every use you mentioned for these features can be accomplished without them, albeit at a performance penalty in some cases.  But C# (and .NET in general) isn't designed to be a high-performance language.  (I'm guessing that "faster than Java" was the performance goal.)

That's not to say that certain performance considerations haven't been afforded.  Indeed, such features as pointers, `stackalloc`, and certain optimized framework functions exist largely to boost performance in certain situations.

Generics, which I'd say have the *primary* benefit of type safety, also improve performance similarly to `TypedReference` by avoiding boxing and unboxing.  In fact, I was wondering why you'd prefer this:

```
static void call(Action<int, TypedReference> action, TypedReference state){
    action(0, state);
}
```

to this:

```
static void call<T>(Action<int, T> action, T state){
    action(0, state);
}
```

The trade-offs, as I see them, are that the former requires fewer JITs (and, it follows, less memory), while the latter is more familiar and, I would assume, slightly faster (by avoiding pointer dereferencing).

I'd call `TypedReference` and friends implementation details.  You've pointed out some neat uses for them, and I think they're worth exploring, but the usual caveat of relying on implementation details applies—the next version may break your code.

Comment: Huh...  "you don't need them" -- I should've seen that coming. :-)
That's true but it's also not true. What do you define as "need"? Are extension methods really "needed", for example?
Regarding your question of using generics in `call()`: It's because the code isn't always so cohesive -- I was referring more to an example more like that of `IAsyncResult.State`, where introducing generics would simply not be feasable because all of a sudden it would introduce generics for every class/method involved.
+1 for the answer, though... especially for pointing out the "faster than Java" part. :]

Comment: Oh, and another point: `TypedReference` will probably *not* be undergoing breaking changes anytime soon, given that [FieldInfo.SetValueDirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.setvaluedirect.aspx), which is public and probably used by some developers, depends on it. :)

Comment: Ah, but you *do* need extension methods, to support LINQ.  Anyway, I'm not really talking about a nice-to-have/need-to-have difference.  I wouldn't call `TypedReference` either of those.  (The atrocious syntax and overall unwieldiness disqualify it, in my mind, from the nice-to-have category.)  I'd say it's just a good thing to have around when you really need to trim a few microseconds here and there.  That said, I thinking of a couple of places in my own code that I'm going to go look at right now, to see if I can optimize them using the techniques you pointed out.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the syntax is pretty horrific. But once you wrap what you need inside other functions, the results just become (rather beautiful) function calls (e.g. `SizeOf<T>()`, `Read<T>(IntPtr)`, `Write<T>(IntPtr, T)`, `AddressOf<T>(ref T)`, `T2 Cast<T1, T2>(T1)`, `Set<T1, T2>(ref T1, T2)`, etc.). (`Cast()` and `Set()` would be useful for turning the "specializing generics" example into something much less ugly, like `Set(ref value, 1)` in my example.)
And haha okay, let us know here if you manage to optimize anything; it'll be interesting to know. :)

Comment: @P Daddy: Just out of curiosity, were you able to get any optimizations using these methods?

Comment: @Merhdad: I was working on a binary object serializer/deserializer at the time for interprocess/interhost communications (TCP and pipes). My goals were to make it as small (in terms of bytes sent over the wire) and fast (in terms of time spent serializing and deserializing) as possible. I thought I might avoid some boxing and unboxing with `TypedReference`s, but IIRC, the only place I was able to avoid boxing *somewhere* was with the elements of single-dimensional arrays of primitives. The slight speed benefit here wasn't worth the complexity it added to the entire project, so I took it out.

Comment: @Mehrdad:  Oops, I spelled your name wrong the first time.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @P Daddy: Ah interesting, ok. And haha no problem! :)

Comment: Given `delegate void ActByRef<T1,T2>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2);` a collection of type `T` could provide a method `ActOnItem<TParam>(int index, ActByRef<T,TParam> proc, ref TParam param)`, but the JITter would have to create a different version of the method for every value type `TParam`.  Using a typed reference would allow one JITted version of the method to work with all parameter types.

Answer (score 4):

I can't figure out whether this question's title is supposed to be sarcastic: It has been [long-established](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14277068/147511) that `TypedReference` is the slow, bloated, ugly cousin of 'true' managed pointers, the latter being what we get with **C++/CLI** `interior_ptr<T>`, or even traditional by-reference (`ref`/`out`) parameters in **C#**.
In fact, it's pretty hard to make `TypedReference` even reach the baseline performance of just using an integer to re-index off the original CLR array every time.

The sad details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14277068/147511), but ***thankfully, none of this matters now...***

> *This question is now rendered moot by the new **[ref locals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns)** and **[ref return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns)** features in **C# 7***

These new language features provide prominent, first-class support in **C#** for declaring, sharing, and manipulating true `CLR` ***managed reference type***-types in carefully prescibed situations.

The use restrictions are no stricter than what was previously required for `TypedReference` (and the performance is literally [jumping from worst to best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14277068/147511)), so I see no remaining conceivable use case in **C#** for `TypedReference`. For example, previously there was no way to persist a `TypedReference` in the `GC` heap, so the same being true of the superior managed pointers now is not a take-away.

And obviously, the demise of `TypedReference`—or its nearly complete deprecation at least—means throw `__makeref` on the junkheap as well.