# Anonymous method with a variable number of parameters

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function, parameters

I have the following code that creates an instance of an anonymous type having a method as the only member:

```
var test = new { 
    f = new Func<int, int>(x => x)
};
```

I want to implement a function that sums up all of its parameters, regardless of how many are passed. This is how a normal method would look like:

```
int Sum(params int[] values) { 
    int res = 0;
    foreach(var i in values) res += i;
    return res;
}
```

However, I don´t know if this would work for anonymous methods. I tried out `Func<params int[], int>`, but obviously that won´t compile. Is there any way to write an anonymous method with a variable list of parameters, or at least with optional args?

EDIT: What I´d like to achieve is to call the (anonymous) sum-method like this: `test.Sum(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: Given that Func is defined 17 ways Func<TResult> to Func<T1 ... T16, TResult> I believe is a strong indicator that what you want cannot be done.  Otherwise MSFT would have done it that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to achieve this, first you need to declare a delegate:

```
delegate int ParamsDelegate(params int[] args);
```

And then use it when assigning the method property of your anonymously typed object.

```
var test = new {
    Sum = new ParamsDelegate(x => x.Sum()) // x is an array
};
```

Then you have two ways of calling this method:

1) `int sum = test.Sum(new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });`

2) `int sum = test.Sum(1, 2, 3, 4);`

Comment: Yeap, that should do the job. Thanks

Comment: @IvanStoev sure it would. But that is not what the OP was asking about (I believe).

Comment: Hmm, "What I´d like to achieve is to call the (anonymous) sum-method like test.Sum(1, 2, 3, 4)"

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you. Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One option that comes to my mind is to simply use an array (or any other sort of `IEnumerable`) as type-parameter for the function:

```
f = new Func<IEnumerable<int>, int> ( x => foreach(var i in x) ... )
```

Simlar to the appraoch of Dmytro (which I prefer more) we´d call it by creating an array:

```
var s = test.f(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially your anonymous type does not contain a method, but instead a property of type `Func<,>`. C# does not support variadic generics i.e. you can't have generic with variable number of parameters. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6845081/85620).

What you can do instead:

1. For aggregate like functions consider using of IEnumerable as generic parameter for `Func<,>`. For example: `Func<IEnumerable<int>, int>(...)`.
2. Here is [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4059664/8562) that could be useful for you.