# Save a object reference for future usage using ref keyword

Tags: c#, properties, ref

Say I have a simple class like this:

```
public class ReferenceChanger<T> 
{
    public T SavedElement { get; private set; }

    public ReferenceChanger(T elementToSave)
    {
        SavedElement = elementToSave;
    }

    // This method would change the original variable (given as a constructor argument)
    public void SetNewReference(T newElement)
    {
        SavedElement = newElement;
    }
}
```

This class saves an element given to its constructor, whatever *element* is. However, the "SavedElement" (its backing field) is a reference to the object given at the time of instance creation.

Is there any way to save a **reference to a variable** (as with using ref keyword), so that if the original item passed to the constructor changes, the *SavedElement* would automatically reflect the change, almost as if the object was passed with the **ref** keyword? *(Even if I use the **ref** keyword, I would not be able to save the reference that way.)*

Updated to make intentions more clear:

```
public class ExampleClass 
{
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    ExampleClass temp = new ExampleClass();
    temp.Numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }; 

    ReferenceChanger<List<int>> changer = new ReferenceChanger<List<int>>(temp.Numbers);
    // Here, a reference to the List<int> instance (containing 1,2,3) is stored in changer's SavedElement

    // Then I do this:
    changer.SetNewReference(new List<int>() { 5, 6, 7 });

    // Now, only changer's SavedElement was changed, but temp's property Numbers was not changed.
    // Is there a way to change the temp's property Numbers from the changer?
}
```

Comment: seeing that classes are automatically reference types, in change in the object passed to your ctor should be reflected in your SavedElement, as it's merely referencing that object, it's not being passed by value, but by reference.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want code that consumed the value of `SavedElement` before the call to `SetNewReference` to subsequently carry out operations on the new version of `SavedElement`?

Comment: If so, just pass the whole instance of ReferenceChanger to the operation and have it call SavedElement when it needs to. It'll always use the "latest" reference.

Comment: @Tony I think you have misunderstood my question. I will add some more code that will describe it. Changes in the referenced object will be visible, but not changes OF THE OBJECT in its variable.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, as long as it's a mutable reference type (class), you can do this.  A variable of a reference type (class) is already a reference.  Using ref on a reference type passes a reference to the reference.

Comment: If the saved reference and original reference both continue to reference the same object, they both see any changes made inside or outside that wrapper class.

Comment: The commenters are missing the point of the question. 1) T is not constrained to a reference type. 2) He wants to capture a reference to the *variable* (he cannot do this, for the record), so that when the *variable* changes, he'll see it. @Kornelije, if you can confirm that you want to observe changes to the variable, and not just the variable's original object, that might help. Or maybe I'm the one missing the point, you can confirm that, too.

Comment: @Anthony: Thanks for the reply. It seems you did understand my intentions (and my bad English). I have posted some more code that would explain what I need. And I guess you have already answered the question :)

Comment: @Kornelije: Okay, now we see, you want a reference to your reference so that when the reference itself changes its target, you want the stored reference to do the same.  Wasn't sure if you were talkign about changes inside the object, or to the reference.  But it is the reference.

Comment: @Kornelije: after seeing the update, Anthony is right, you can't store a reference to a variable.  You could wrap it in a new class called ListManager and then have both your program and the class hold a reference to that, so that the reference is one level removed...

Comment: @James: Thanks. I just wanted to be sure that there is nothing intrinsic to C# that enables such a thing. Maybe something can be done with closure, but I guess I could slightly change the design.

Comment: One thought is that you could capture it via a lambda, passing the lambda into the class instead of the variable directly. Lambdas close over the variable, so any changes to it would be observed elsewhere if you happened to pass it around. Not calling it a good idea, mind you, and I haven't fully thought it through, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `TypedReference` and the `__makeref` keyword.

Warning: they're poorly documented and not in the standardized part of C#.

There's a lot more information in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764573/why-is-typedreference-behind-the-scenes-its-so-fast-and-safe-almost-magical)

Answer (score 0):

All classes in C# are reference objects so what you have coded should update the value of `SavedElement`.  However, if `T` is a primitive type (e.g., int, string, etc.), this would not work since these are set by value.  You would need to put a constraint on `T` to make sure it's a class.

Comment: one slight correction - string is a reference type, it just happens to be an immutable reference type.  You can have two string variables pointing to the exact same instance of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot normally capture a reference to a variable and store it as a property. One hackish solution (not really suggesting it's a good idea, I'd explore other avenues first) is to capture it in a closure and pass the closure around. Closures capture variables, not values. As a result, changes to variables can be observed elsewhere. For example, given

```
class Foo
{
    public int Baz { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    private Func<Foo> fooGetter;

    public Bar(Func<Foo> fooGetter)
    {
        this.fooGetter = fooGetter;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fooGetter().Baz);
    }
}
```

You can have

```
Foo foo = new Foo() { Baz = 1 };
Bar bar = new Bar(() => foo);
bar.Do();
foo = new Foo() { Baz = 2 };
bar.Do();
```

Changes to the variable `foo` are observed, since that is what the caller enclosed in the lambda. Had the caller simply said `() => new Foo()`, you would (of course) not observe any changes.