# C# Reflection: What is the difference between FieldInfo.SetValue() and FieldInfo.SetValueDirect()?

Tags: c#, reflection, fieldinfo

The `FieldInfo` documentation I was able to find did not compare and contrast these two methods. I am interested in understanding when one should be used over the other (preferably with a small code snippet).

Comment: So do you have a `TypedReference` you can use for `SetValueDirect`?

Comment: Does `SetValueDirect()` run faster than `SetValue()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SetValueDirect takes a TypedReference parameter, and as such it is to be used when varargs parameter interoperability is needed. This performs no boxing/unboxing of values and no access checking. It runs faster than SetValue.

SetValue on the other hand operates on pretty much everything else. It performs boxing/unboxing of the parameter where needed, and also checks for access.

There are SO's that discuss TypedReferences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711393/practical-uses-of-typedreference) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764573/why-is-typedreference-behind-the-scenes-its-so-fast-and-safe-almost-magical) - there are code examples in both.