# c# ?: Operator with ref parameter

Tags: c#, logical-operators

I have the following class:

```
public class SubStredisko
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public VyplatnePasky VyplatnaPaska { get; set; }
    public MzdoveNaklady MzdoveNaklady { get; set; }
    public Poistne Poistne { get; set; }
}
```

then I have two `SubStredisko` items, where one of them is definitely `null`. What I am trying to do, is that I have a separate method, which does some processing with `SubStredisko`, such as changes values of `VyplatnaPaska` etc. Here is what it looks like:

```
    private static void VyplatnePasky_Items(ref Stredisko stredisko, XElement myElement)
    {
        //some logic here
    }
```

What I try to do now (what I have problem with) is to call this method using the `?:` operator in the following way:

```
VyplatnePasky_Items((sPracovisko == null) ? ref sPracovisko_Dohodari : ref sPracovisko,xElement);
```

However it highlights `sPracovisko_Dohodari` and `sPracovisko` with the following error: `Syntax error, ':' expected`.

I tried to put them in brackets separately, however with no luck.
What am I doing wrong?

P.S. `sPracovisko` and `sPracovisko_Dohodari` are of type `SubStredisko`.

P.S.2: Just a quick thought - maybe I don't even need a `ref` parameter in here? I am not quite sure if in this case a new object will be created, or I will be (in my void) directly changing values of that specific object.

Comment: In that `VyplatnePasky_Items` method, are you assigning a new value to `stredisko`? If not, then you don't need thar ref, even if you *are* assigning new values to properties of that stredisko.

Comment: `SubStredisko` is a `class` (and not a `struct`), so it's a reference type. So if you just pass it like `(sPracovisko == null) ? sPracovisko_Dohodari : sPracovisko` (without the `ref`), then you will be able to manipulate the contents of the referenced object directly. So no "new object" will be created. The only thing you would need the `ref` keyword for would be if you want to be able to change what object the *variable* (`sPracovisko` or `sPracovisko_Dohodari`) references.

Comment: There are two issues. First, if both `sPracovisko` and `sPracovisko_Dohodari` are of type `Stredisko` you ***can*** now with C# 7 use the ternary operator: `VyplatnePasky_Items(ref (sPracovisko == null ? ref sPracovisko_Dohodari : ref sPracovisko), xElement)`. However, the more general problem is that you said that those types are `SubStredisko` rather than `Stredisko`, and you can't pass types by-reference unless they match the exact type. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45124463/147511) for explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use an expression for a `ref` parameter. You need two calls:

```
if (sPracovisko == null) {
  VyplatnePasky_Items(ref sPracovisko_Dohodari, xElement);
} else {
  VyplatnePasky_Items(ref sPracovisko, xElement);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One additional questions (as P.S.2) - do I actually need a **ref** parameter in here? Will a new object be created without a **ref**?

Comment: @RobertJ.: You only need the `ref` parameter if you are going to assign something to the `sPracovisko_Dohodari`/`sPracovisko` variable inside the method. Without the `ref` keyword the parameter is sent by value, which means that a reference type is sent as a copy of the reference to the object. You will still be able to change the content in the object.

Comment: See my comment above. With C# 7 you can now use **ref** in a ternary operator: `ref T a = ref (i == 0 ? ref b : ref c);`. (The r-value in this example can also be passed into `ref`-taking functions without needing to be assigned to a ref-local).

Comment: ...And btw, can [also be used as an l-value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50672315/147511), i.e. on the left-hand side of an assignment.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments by @GlennSlayden, you can use `?:` (ternary conditionals) with `ref` from C# 7 / VS2017, using the following syntax:

```cs
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
bool condition = true;

ref int i = ref (condition ? ref a : ref b);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ref` argument has to be a *variable*.  It cannot be an ternary expression like you're trying to do. You can do this instead:

```
var inputParameter = sPracovisko == null ? sPracovisko_Dohodari : sPracovisko;
VyplatnePasky_Items(ref inputParameter, xElement);
```

Note that, with the code above, the changes will be reflected on the `inputParamter`, and it won't affect the other two variables.  If you want the variables themselves to be changed, then go with @Guffa's answer.

Comment: I thought of this approach, however in this case we are creating one additional object in a memory, aren't we? This will be done in a loop and therefore I wanted to minimize memory consumption.

Comment: @RobertJ. no you're not creating an additional object. `SubStredisko` is a class; therefore, it is a _reference type_, which means it simply references  the same object.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
VyplatnePasky_Items(((sPracovisko == null) ? ref sPracovisko_Dohodari :   sPracovisko),xElement);
```

or

```
VyplatnePasky_Items(((sPracovisko == null) ? ref sPracovisko_Dohodari :   sPracovisko) out,xElement);
```