# TypeReference and FieldInfo.SetValueDirect is not persistent

Tags: c#, struct

I am using a TypedReference to set a value in a structure with FieldInfo.SetValueDirect ( [Practical uses of TypedReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711393/practical-uses-of-typedreference) ).

The overall goal is to have a generic struct-to-buffer and buffer-to-struct function that will read a TCP data stream
directly into a c-style structure ([Bit fields in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464/bit-fields-in-c-sharp)).

Thanks to some great posts,I have this working for my purposes so far, but I can't find a way to make the TypeReference work.

This code is a stripped version of the project to illustrate the last problem: the structure is being correctly filled
from the buffer using FieldInfo.SetValueDirect(), but it loses scope when I leave the routine.

```
    public class structL4
    {
        public UInt16 Label;
    }

    static class StructConvert
    {
        public static void BufferToStruct<T>(byte[] buffer, int offset, T t) where T : struct
        {
            UInt16 val;
            foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo f in t.GetType().GetFields())
            {
                val = BitConverter.ToUint16(buffer,offset);
                TypedReference reference = __makeref(t);
                f.SetValueDirect(reference, val); // t.Label now contains the right value but is lost
            }
        }

        public static void StructToBuffer<T>(T t, byte[] buffer, int offset) where T : struct
        {
            UInt16 val;
            foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo f in t.GetType().GetFields())
            {
                val = (UInt16)f.GetValue(t);
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(val), 0, buffer, offset, sizeof(UInt16));
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        structL4 L0 = new structL4();
        structL4 L1 = new structL4();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];

        L0.Label = 0x8C54;

        StructConvert.StructToBuffer(L0, buffer, 0);  // works
        StructConvert.BufferToStruct(buffer,0,L1);    // does not work.
    }
```

I would like BufferToStruct() to act on the passed struct by reference so I don't have to assign it, but I'm having trouble finding a solution the compiler is happy with.

Overall the idea works fine, at least for StructToBuffer(), which I will use with dozens of bitwise C-type structs.

I'm a bit out of my league with TypeReference and FieldInfo methods; have only been using C# for a short time. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "Value Types" are copied and the copy is passed into methods by default, your actual struct isn't modified.

You either return a struct and assign it or pass the struct by `ref`.

```
public static void BufferToStruct<T>(byte[] buffer, int offset, ref T t) where T : struct//Note the ref modifier
```

Then call it as

```
StructConvert.BufferToStruct(buffer,0,ref L1);
```

Comment: aargh.  Should have caught that. Thank you very much!!